# Most accurate way to divide two numbers in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, division

I have a table with expense items and their amount.  For certain types of expense items, I need to run a script that takes the amount and distribute it over the other items.  I have this mostly working, however i'm finding that the amount distributed isn't the exact amount that I am starting with, and assume it's a rounding issue.  I'm currently using `numeric(36,20)`

An example is the following location.
Original data:

```
Location    acct    amt                     Item
Alpha       0121    291375.780000000000000  SWAdm
Alpha       0122    14854.250000000000000   SWAdm
Alpha       0127    12190.500000000000000   SWAdm
Alpha       1121    116777.740000000000000  SWOther
Alpha       1122    7369.390000000000000    SWOther
Alpha       1127    91380.680000000000000   SWOther
Alpha       1195    5334.820000000000000    SWAL
Alpha       1310    1164.950000000000000    SWSPLIT
```

New Data:

```
Location    Acct    Smt             Item    OrigAmt                 ALAdjust    SplitAdjust     RecAdjust
Alpha       0121    292667.718230   SWAdm   291375.780000000000000  1060.446505 231.491725  0.000000
Alpha       0122    16146.188230    SWAdm   14854.250000000000000   1060.446505 231.491725  0.000000
Alpha       0127    13482.438230    SWAdm   12190.500000000000000   1060.446505 231.491725  0.000000
Alpha       1121    117652.208168   SWOther 116777.740000000000000  717.779450  156.688718  0.000000
Alpha       1122    8243.858168     SWOther 7369.390000000000000    717.779450  156.688718  0.000000
Alpha       1127    92255.148168    SWOther 91380.680000000000000   717.779450  156.688718  0.000000
```

The values for SWAL and SWSplit are distributed over SWAdm and SWOther, based on the relative total values of SWAdm and SWOther.

So in this case, `SWAdm total = 318420.53`, `SWOther = 215527.81`.  To get the distributed value, it's `SWAL/(SWAdm+SWOther)`.  That is then multiplied by the SWAdm value to get the % of SWAL applied to SWAdm.  This value is then divided evenly across the individual SWAdm items.

I believe i'm having rounding issues, but can't easily see how to fix them.  Any ideas?

Comment: where this ALAAdjust and Split comes ?? hardcoded @matt

Comment: You can use DECIMAL(25,13)

Comment: @RahulTripathi, may I know why?

Comment: @FelixPamittan:- 12 digits before decimal and 13 after it. p+s less than 38. Just a guess!

Comment: When I was doing similar calculations for accounting purposes (i.e. when the numbers are money, not just some measurements), I was following whatever procedure accountant told me to follow. This is business (tax office) rules, not math rules. I ended up having two-pass algorithm. First calculate amounts with full precision and round final row value to 2 decimal places (cents) at the very end. Then sum up rounded values and compare the sum to original sum. Usually a small difference accumulates. This difference is added to the last row to make the totals match exactly to the cent.

Comment: ALAdjust etc is the audit trail from the distribution of SWAL.  If you sum ALAdjust, it should equal SWAL.  Cheers for that Vladimir, i'll give that method a shot. I assume that will fix it.